# GAS Add on menus not showing up in Auth Mode NONE

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I've been going through the Google Workplace Marketplace add-on publishing process and I've been having trouble with my onOpen function and auth modes. I thought I had it corrected but when I test it as an add on using the legacy editor with it installed but not enabled (auth mode NONE), no menu shows up and I get the following message in the console:

> Google Apps Script: Exception: You do not have permission to perform
> that action.

When I run the onOpen function in the editor while testing it as an add-on I continuously get an a error saying the following for line 6 (the declaration for the menu variable in onOpen)

> Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.

My code is below. I've been looking through other answers on StackOverflow but haven't been able to find any solutions. I am not using a teams drive which was mentioned elsewhere as being an issue. I also went through and removed any global variable declarations with no luck. So I'm a bit stumped.

```
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
  if (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
    menu.addItem('Enable Khan2Canvas','mainMenu');
    menu.addToUi();
  } else {
    mainMenu();
  }
}

function mainMenu() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Import Data', 'importDataMenu')
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Send Scores')
        .addItem('Send All Assignments', 'sendAllMenu')
        .addItem('Send Selected Assignments', 'sendSelectedMenu')
        .addItem('Clear Selections', 'resetSelectedMenu'))
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Setup')
        .addItem("Launch Setup", "launchSetupMenu")
        .addItem("Update Sheet", "updateSheetMenu")
        .addItem("Install Triggers", 'installTriggersMenu')
        .addItem("Create Data Folder", "createDataFolderMenu")
        .addItem("Import Roster", "importRosterMenu")
        .addItem("Download Courses", "downloadCoursesMenu"))        
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Reformat')
        .addItem("Scores", 'formatScoresMenu')        
        .addItem("Settings", 'formatSettingsMenu')
        .addItem("DATA", 'formatDATAMenu')
        .addItem("All", 'formatAllMenu'))
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Rebuild')
        .addItem("Scores", 'rebuildScoresMenu')        
        .addItem("Settings", 'rebuildSettingsMenu')
        .addItem("DATA", 'rebuildDATAMenu')
        .addItem("All", 'rebuildAllMenu'))
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Reset')
        .addItem("New Grading Term", 'newGradingTermMenu')        
        .addItem("New Class", 'newClassMenu')
        //.addItem("New Academic Year",'newAcademicYearMenu')
        .addItem("All", 'resetAllMenu'))
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Info')
        .addItem("Documentation", 'documentationMenu')        
        //.addItem("License", 'licenseModal')
        .addItem("Donate", 'donateMenu')
        .addItem("Contact", 'contactMenu')
        .addItem("About", 'aboutModal'))
      .addItem("Show/Hide Options", "showHideOptionsMenu")
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: try your script in a new spreadsheet with new script project and test the addon

Comment: @TheMaster I went ahead and did this using only the code I have above and aside from there being an error with menu.addItem('Enable Khan2Canvas','mainMenu').addtoUi(); (corrected above now) it worked fine. Why is this? Is there something wrong elsewhere in my project? Is it the sheet it is associated with right now?

Comment: Probably you need to update the correct version of the script.

Comment: Huh. I went in and created a new version under Manage Versions, tested it as an add-on with that new version, and it worked. The only thing I can see as being different was I was using "Test with lastest code" which I assumed to be the last saved copy of the code but maybe that refers to the lastest version created in the version manager? Anyways, it seems to be working now. Thanks